# Reverse for 'viewpost' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['int:post\\.id$']. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to learn django and while making a viewport view, I came up with this error saying `Reverse for 'viewpost' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['int:post\\.id$']` I don't understand what is the mistake I am doing

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def main(request):
    return render(request, "blog/index.html", {"Posts":Post.objects.all()})

def viewpost(request):
    
    return render(request, "blog/viewpost.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.main, name = 'main'),
    path('viewpost/int:pk/', views.viewpost, name = 'viewpost')
    
]
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'blog/layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Physics Blog</h1>
    
    {% for post in Posts %}
        <fieldset>
            <a href = "{% url 'viewpost' post.id %}"><h2>{{ post.Title }}</h2></a>
            <a href = "{% url 'viewpost' post.id %}"><h4>{{ post.Description }}</h4></a>
            <a href = "{% url 'viewpost' post.id %}"><h6>{{ post.Author }}</h6></a>   
        </fieldset>   
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    

{% endblock %}
```

viewpost.html

```
{% extends 'blog/layout.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ post.Title }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ post.Description }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ post.Author }}</h1>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
path('viewpost/int:pk/', views.viewpost, name = 'viewpost')
```

`int:pk` is missing the angular brackets. Change it to

```
path('viewpost/<int:pk>/', views.viewpost, name='viewpost')
```

The `path()` in your question doesn't seem to match `'int:post\\.id$` in the error message. So make sure you have saved the file and restarted `runserver`.

You'll also have to change `viewpost` so that it accepts the pk.

```
def viewpost(request, pk):
```